# Options to display 20 - 200 items for user selection in a winform app?

Tags: .net, winforms, custom-controls, devexpress, krypton-toolkit

I have need of a checked combobox control like this one --> [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=XtraEditors/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsCheckedComboBoxEdittopic.htm&levelup=true) *(I am using this now and would like to move away from DevExpress for many many reasons)*

**I am willing to attempt my own control though I would like*(read need)* some direction.**

I am willing to use [Krypton's Free Tools](http://www.componentfactory.com/free-windows-forms-controls.php) and extend them (*if possible*) though; I cannot, at this time, pay for the source code.

I am willing to listen to alternative methods of displaying data to my users.

**My situation is this:**  I have multiple place's where I need to display 20 - 100+ possible items to select.  In the WebApp version there was just a popup with all the check boxes listed and you scrolled away.  I would really like to AVOID scrolling of the main screen in my desktop-ported version!

Any and all suggestions welcome!

Comment: Are you saying you'd like to avoid scrolling, even when the user clicks on the combo box? If so, and I understand you correctly, you want a combo box to appear with potentially over 100 items all displayed at once? That seems like a bit much.

Comment: No, I am saying that was the web version's way of doing it.  Kinda of.  They had a pop up window that showed over a 100 items at once.  I want a dropdown that show's, maybe, 10-20 and they scroll inside that dropdown.  OR I am open to any alternative ideas to display that much info.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DevExpress control looks like a popup form placed right under an ordinary combo box.  That would be simple enough to do.

Comment: So just place a `checklistbox` in a `combobox`?  I am guessing it isn't that simple...  Maybe place a `checklistbox` in a `groupbox` and then set the visibility to `False`, place it directly under a `button` and have the `btnClickEvent()` toggle the visibility...?

Comment: Actually, what you would probably want to do is pop up a form underneath an ordinary textbox.  You would need a button next to the textbox that masquerades as the popdown control, and you can put whatever you want onto the form.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can use the DevExpress checked combobox control, which is a part of the XtraEditor library, free of charge :)

[Over 40 Individual Controls – Free of Charge](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/WebRegistration/)

It looks like the following components are available for free:

- The XtraEditors Library
- The XtraNavBar Suite
- ASPxMenu
- ASPxSiteMapControl

According to the link: ... 
*you will be able to download, install, and use these controls free of charge. The applications you create with these controls can be distributed royalty free (see the EULA that accompanies the products for more information)...*

See more details on the offer in the link above.

I do not work for DevExpress and I have no idea when this offer will end, though :).

Comment: See notation in original question... This offer has been around for awhile and if your app is large enough to need multiple controls then this isn't too bad an idea.  Unfortunately, if you only need a few controls, this library is overkill.  It comes in at 6232kb vs ,say, the Krypton toolkit at 2128kb.  Thank you for the suggestion and your time.

Comment: Six megabytes doesn't seem like a lot to me, unless you require dozens of libraries.

Comment: +1: it works and it's free. Add 6 Mb to the deployment package or spend the time to roll your own? If it's a hobby project and you really want to learn how to create one, then sure, create one... if it's for work: it seems like an easy choice to me.